# Delete current terminal input line

Tags: c, terminal, chat, stdout, stdin

I am trying to code a little console chat-program in C on linux.

So far I coded it in a way that both chatting partners are only able to alternately send/recv, because these function calls are blocking by default.

Now I would like to modify that program, so that both are able to send and receive simultaneously.

The problem that I find is, that once you typed some input to the terminal, I don't know how to output received messages, without messing up the current input line of the terminal.

If there was a way to delete that current input line, you could temporarily save that line, print the new message and put the input line right back.

However, I was not able to find a solution for this problem on the internet.

Is it possible to delete the current input line, and if not, how else could I achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you tried to look into [terminal escapes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) ?

Comment: I _think_ this is the sort of thing that `ncurses` does, but having never used it for  myself, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Zelnes Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into **ncurses** as Edd said in his comment.
It would allow you to easily manage contents in your terminal window, which sounds like a good idea for your chat program.
All you'd need to do is store your messages in 2 character arrays:

`char incoming[MSG_MAX]`
and
`char outgoing[MSG_MAX]`

Then you can output those messages wherever you want in your terminal window, since ncurses allows you to specify *x,y* coordinates on where to put your text.
Then a simple wrapper for one of ncurses `erase()` family functions would allow you to delete characters from specify *x,y* coordinates in your terminal window.

Edit: `MSG_MAX` is not an actual ncurses macro.